# Accessing and Modifying a Child node from a Parent node

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

Hi I am trying to extend the ZoomRow sample channel. In essence I am adding a rectangle to each row item with a set color and I am trying to update the color when the item is in focus.

Here is the child component. I added a detailsTest field with an alias to the rectangle color.

```
<component name="SimpleGridItem" extends="Group">

<interface>
  <field id="width" type="float" alias="itemPoster.width" />
  <field id="height" type="float" alias="itemPoster.height" /> 
  <field id="detailsTest" type="float" alias="details.color" /> 
  <field id="itemContent" type="node" onChange="itemContentChanged"/> 
</interface>

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[
    function itemContentChanged()
    m.itemPoster.uri = m.top.itemContent.HDPOSTERURL
    end function

    function init()
        m.itemPoster  = m.top.findNode("itemPoster")
    end function
]]>
</script>

<children>
<Poster id="itemPoster" />
<Rectangle 
  id="details"
  width="575"
  height="80"
  color="0x373B3E"
>
  <LayoutGroup
    vertAlignment="center"
    horizAlignment="center"
    translation="[80, 40]"
  >
    <Label
      id="title"
      text="lets go"
      width="364" 
      horizAlign="center"
      wrap="true"
      lineSpacing="-2" 
    />
  </LayoutGroup>
</Rectangle>
</children>

</component>
```

Here is the parent component. I am updating the rectangle color in the focusChanged and rowItemFocusedChanged methods. I am getting an invalid expression in the rowItemFocusedChanged method. I am also not seeing any change on screen for the focusChanged method and was wondering what I am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

````
<component name="ZoomRowListTestScene" extends="Scene">

<script type="text/brightscript" >
<![CDATA[

    function init()
        print "in ZoomRowListTestScene init()"
        
        m.zoomRowList = m.top.findNode("theZoomRowList")

        m.zoomRowList.translation = [193, 110]

        m.zoomRowList.observeField("scrollingStatus", "scrollingStatusChanged")
        m.zoomRowList.observeField("rowItemFocused", "rowItemFocusedChanged")
        m.zoomRowList.observeField("rowFocused", "rowFocusedChanged")

        m.scrollingStatusLabel = m.top.findNode("scrollingStatusLabel")
        m.rowItemFocusedLabel = m.top.findNode("rowItemFocusedLabel")
        m.rowFocusedLabel = m.top.findNode("rowFocusedLabel")

        m.top.visible = true

        m.top.observeField("focusedChild", "focusChanged")

        m.readerTask = createObject("roSGNode", "RowListContentTask")
        m.readerTask.observeField("content", "gotContent")
        m.readerTask.control = "RUN"

        m.zoomRowList.visible = false
        m.zoomRowList.setFocus(true)
    end function

    function gotContent()
        if m.readerTask.content=invalid
            print "invalid readerTask.content"
        else
            m.zoomRowList.content = m.readerTask.content
        m.zoomRowList.visible = true
        end if
    end function

    function focusChanged()
        if m.top.isInFocusChain()
        if not m.zoomRowList.hasFocus()
                m.zoomRowList.setFocus(true)
                m.zoomRowList.detailsTest.color = "0x0xE55539"
            end if
        end if
    end function

    function rowFocused()
'        print "grid row "; m.zoomRowList.rowFocused; " focused"
    end function

    function rowSelected()
'        print "grid row "; m.zoomRowList.rowSelected; " selected"
    end function
    
    function updateCurrFocusRow()
        m.currFocusRowLabel.text = "currFocusRow: " + m.zoomRowList.currFocusRow.toStr()
    end function

    function scrollingStatusChanged()
        m.scrollingStatusLabel.text = "scrollingStatus is: " + m.zoomRowList.scrollingStatus.toStr()
    end function

    function rowItemFocusedChanged()
        m.rowItemFocusedLabel.text = "rowItemFocused is: " + m.zoomRowList.rowItemFocused[0].toStr() + " " + m.zoomRowList.rowItemFocused[1].toStr()
        m.zoomRowList.detailsTest.color = "0x0xE55539"
    end function

    function rowFocusedChanged()
        m.rowFocusedLabel.text = "rowFocused is: " + m.zoomRowList.rowFocused.toStr()
    end function

'    function onKeyEvent(key as string, press as boolean) as boolean
'    end function
]]>
</script>

<children>
<ZoomRowList 
    id="theZoomRowList"
    itemComponentName="SimpleGridItem"
/>
<Label id="scrollingStatusLabel" text="scrollingStatus: false" translation="[100,20]"/>
<Label id="rowItemFocusedLabel" text="rowItemFocused: 0, 0" translation="[500,20]" />
<Label id="rowFocusedLabel" text="rowFocused: 0" translation="[900, 20]"/>
</children>

</component>```
````

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you added `detailsTest` field for the `SimpleGridItem` which is used as a component for `ZoomRowList`. And then you're trying to update that field in the `ZoomRowList`:
`m.zoomRowList.detailsTest.color = "0x0xE55539"`

The problem is that `SimpleGridItem` is a separate component so in the `ZoomRowList` such field doesn't exist and it should be crashing there. Have you encountered a crash?

To achieve the goal you want I would suggest handling it inside the `SimpleGridItem`. For ex.: you could set an observer for `itemHasFocus`and then handle it in callback.